# Is it permissible to learn Hilchot Teshuva on Tisha Beav?

Tags: torah-study, fast-days, tisha-bav, simchah-joy-happiness

The Shulchan Aruch paskens (OC 554) that it is forbidden to learn most parts of Torah on Tisha Beav, except for a few small sections about aveilut.
The question is: the Shulchan Aruch doesn't explicitly mention Hilchot Teshuva, but would it be permissible to do so?
The Rambam (Hilchot Taaniot) says that the point of fasts is to do Teshuva. Seemingly learning Hilchot Teshuva would fit directly in this theme.
What do you guys think/ do you know of any sources?
Thanks so much in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not only is it permissible, but it is correct to do so according to the Meiri (Moed Katan 21a- Aveilus) . The Meiri explains that learning things that arouses one to do teshuva is a good thing. See Piskei Teshuvos 554:2 for more sources.

Rav Eliyashiv in Ashrei HaIsh page. 485 is quoted as holding that one may learn divrei mussar even though it contains aggada,and Midrashei Chazal since one's intention is not to learn ,but rather arouse oneself to do teshuva which is the obligation of the day.

Text of the Meiri:

[image]

Comment: Although he says not to on the first day... maybe Tisha BeAv (especially the morning) has that status?

Comment: It seems that the Shulchan Aruch is not learning it's like the first day since be allows talmud Torah for certain topics.

Comment: @talmidforlife, I dont know how to do text ,only picture of it,sry

Comment: @Joel K there is also a whole machlokes about teffilin ,and it seems that really one should wear teffilin sonce its not like the first day ,the Tur brings this .

Comment: I don't see that the _M'iri_ is on point. The question was about laws of _t'shuva_. The _M'iri_ is discussing things that awaken one's heart to _t'shuva_. Of course one should learn the laws in order to be able to act on them, but I wouldn't say it awakens one's heart to _t'shuva_: one's mind, yes. YMMV of course, but I suspect what I say is true for most people.

Comment: How can you do teshuva if you dont know what to do ,I am sry I dont see where you are coming from.

Comment: @sam I don't see where you're coming from. Very little of rambams hilchot teshuva is necessary to know how to do teshuva. We wear Tefillin on tisha bav but you can't sit around learning Stam all day. You can check a specific shayla if it comes up presumably and that's it.

Comment: Much of Hilchos Teshuvah may "awaken one's heart to teshuva," but I highly doubt that the discussion of, ex., "if you do XYZ you lose your share in the World to Come" in chapter 3, or the discussion of yedi'ah vs. bechirah in chapter 6, or the discussion of Mashiach in chapters 8-9, would fall into this category. Chapters 7 and 10 I think would be the only pieces which even have a chance of counting.